# How to recursively copy in place a FormGroup?

Tags: angular

We're trying to build a generic table component, where items can be added to a table or edited individually. The table has an `addForm` `FormGroup` for editing items before they are added to the form. When the item is added to the from the `addForm` is copied to a `FormArray` with lodash's `cloneDeep()`.

The problem we're running into now is editing a row. Each row in the table has a form that's bound to an `editForm` that exists on the overall component. The idea is to copy the values out of the `FormArray` and into the `editForm` and then make the form visible to the user. Unfortunately we're running into problems with some of our more complicated forms, where we're trying to nest these table components inside each other. I've tried a few different approaches but they each have their own gotcha...

**Using _.cloneDeep()**

If I copy from the `FormArray` to the `editForm` with _.cloneDeep() like we use to copy into the `FormArray` it seems the `formControlName` bindings get messed up. I'm guessing this is because replacing that `FormGroup` in place messes up the some internal angular references to the `FormGroup`? I wind up getting this error:

`this.editForm = _.cloneDeep(this.formArray.controls[index]) as FormGroup;`

```
Error: There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name: 'myControlName'
```

**Using patchValue()**

My other attempt at this was to use the built-in `patchValue()`, but it looks like `patchValue()` doesn't handle `FormArray`s very well.

`this.editForm.patchValue((this.formArray.controls[index] as FormGroup).getRawValue());`

```
> this.formArray.controls[0].controls['treatingPhysicians'].controls[0].controls
  - Object
    - address: FormGroup
    - id: FormControl
    - physicianFullName: FormControl
    - __proto__: Object
> this.editForm.controls['treatingPhysicians'].controls[0].controls
  - []
```

**Writing a custom copy function**

We also have our own custom form copying function laying around, unfortunately it also seems to choke up on `FormArray`s, since it's difficult to tell if the properties on an object in an array should be a control or another nested `FormGroup`.

`this.editForm = this.buildOutValues((this.formArray.controls[index] as FormGroup).getRawValue(), this.editForm);`

```
> this.formArray.controls[0].controls['treatingPhysicians'].controls[0].controls
  - Object
    - address: FormGroup
    - id: FormControl
    - physicianFullName: FormControl
    - __proto__: Object
> this.editForm.controls['treatingPhysicians'].controls[0].controls
   - Object
     - address: FormControl
     - id: FormControl
     - physicianFullName: FormControl
     - __proto__: Object
```

So is there a good way to copy forms and keep all the angular references in tact? Or is there a way we can modify our custom form copying method and still be able to distinguish properties that should be groups and which should be controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by writing a custom form copy function that copies based on the `FormGroup` rather than the value of the form. Using `isinstance` was sufficient to figure out how each control in the `FormGroup` should be copied.

Comment: Can you share the form copy function please. I am facing exactly the same issue and I am most probably going to follow the same technique of custom copy implementation.